# Angular-material: Adding border to a button in the theme

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

My goal is to make all "accent" buttons (`<button mat-raised-button color="accent">`) in my theme to have a blue border, blue text and a white background. I was reading about the custom theme setting in angular-material.

What I could do is, set my "primary" and "accent" colors in a theme and set that to all the button elements. With this, all my primary buttons are solid blue and accent buttons are white.

```
$my-button-primary: mat-palette($my-blue, 500, 200, 800);
$my-button-accent: mat-palette($my-white, 500, 200, 800);

$my-button-theme: mat-light-theme(
  $my-button-primary,
  $my-button-accent
);

@include mat-button-theme($my-button-theme);
```

But, to set a blue border and a blue text, I need to manually write an SCSS style.

```
@mixin buttons-theme($theme) {
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  .mat-raised-button.mat-accent,
  .mat-stroked-button.mat-accent,
  .mat-flat-button.mat-accent,
  .mat-button.mat-accent {
    background-color: white;
    color: mat-color($accent);
    border: solid 1px mat-color($accent);
  }
}
```

Now, is there a way to include the button style while creating the theme? Or is there a better way to write the above code?

Comment: I think what you have is a good solution. I've messed with material themes to a good degree and I don't see a better/more simple method.